# Proving that if $A$ and $B$ are compact spaces, then $A\times B$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, product-space

I am trying to prove that if A and B are compact sets, then AxB is compact as well.

I mostly need feedback on my proof and if it is correct.

I approach with Bolzano-Weierstrauss theorem.

Let Sn be a sequence in AxB, where Sn = (an, bn) for every ordered-pair in AxB. We need to show that for an arbitrary sequence (defined above as Sn) there exists a convergent subsequence. That is, Snk is a converging subsequence such that Snk = (ank, bnk).

Since A is compact, then there exists a sequence an with a convergent subsequence ank.

Since B is compact, then there exists a sequence bn with a convergent subsequence bnk.

Therefore, since ank and bnk converge, Snk = (ank, bnk) must also converge*.

* I'm not really sure how to prove this fact. I guess in other words I want to show that if J and K are convergent sequences then JxK is a convergent sequence? I could probably approach this proof as a lemma and prove it using delta-epsilon, but I feel I am overcomplicating my proof at this point...

Otherwise, does my proof look reasonable? How can it be improved? Or did I muck up the definitions?

Comment: So you are doing "sequentially compact" rather than "compact".  Of course they are the same in metric space, but you never said you were in metric space.  For "compact" you should perhaps argue about open covers having finite subcovers.

Comment: After construction of convergent sequence $(a_{n_k})$ you must take a look at $(b_{n_k})$ which is *not necessarily convergent*. However it contains a convergent $(b_{n_{k_i}})$. Then $((a_{n_{k_i}}),(b_{n_{k_i}}))$ is convergent.

Comment: I am given that A is a subset of R^m and B is a subset of R^n (with both A and B being compact) and AxB = {(x,y) in R^(n+m): x in A, y in A}. I'm not sure what you mean by metric spaces. Could you clarify?

Comment: @drhab - why must I look at (bnk) as being not necessairly convergent? :o I had a suspicion but I wasn't able to reason out this part. furthermore, if it has a convergent subsequence, does this imply the sequence itself is convergent?

Comment: You are searching for a convergent subsequence of $(a_n,b_n)\in A\times B$ right? You can start by observing that there is a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ but that does not provide you necessarily a convergent sequence $(a_{n_k},b_{n_k})$. There is no guarantee that $(b_{n_k})$ will converge as well.

Comment: But if B is compact, and bn is a sequence in B, then shouldn't bnk converge?

Comment: The fact that $B$ is compact only assures you that $(b_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, but it does not assure you that particularly $(b_{n_k})$ is such a convergent subsequence. The $n_k$ are determined by finding $(a_{n_k})$ without taking any notion of sequence $(b_n)$.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, but in that case I also can't guarantee (ank) converges

Comment: You just can start by observing that a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ exists. For construction of a convergent $(a_{n_{k_i}},b_{n_{k_i}})_i$ see my first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let it be that every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence and let it be that every sequence in $B$ has a convergent subsequence.

Let it be that $(a_n,b_n)_n$ is a sequence in $A\times B$.

It is our aim to prove that this sequence has a convergent subsequence.

First we note that $(a_n)_n$ has a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$.

However we are not ready yet, because there is no guarantee that $(b_{n_k})_k$ is a convergent sequence

But we do observe that sequence $(b_{n_k})_k$ has a convergent subsequence $(b_{n_{k_i}})_i$.

Note that $(a_{n_{k_i}})_i$ is a subsequence of the convergent sequence $(a_{n_k})_k$, hence is also convergent.

From this we conclude that $(a_{n_{k_i}},b_{n_{k_i}})_i$ is a convergent subsequence of $(a_n,b_n)$ and we are done.

Comment: This is essentially how I've formalized my proof now. :) Thanks for your help.

My confusion may be with subsequences. When we say (ank) converges, does that mean (ank) converges to its limit at the index k?

Then, we cannot look at (bnk) immediately because it may not converge at this same index k? Ultimately because we need (ank, bnk) to be convergent  so they'd have to converge to the same limit which as I stated may not be entirely possible?

Comment: $(a_{n_k})$ converges if $(a'_k)_k$ converges where $a'_k:=a_{n_k}$. Actually there exists indices $n_1<n_2<n_3<\cdots$ such that $a_{n_1},a_{n_2}, a_{n_3},\dots$ is a convergent sequence. Then $b_{n_1},b_{n_2}, b_{n_3},\dots$ need not converge yet, but we can pick out indices $n_{k_1}<n_{k_2}<\cdots$ such that $b_{n_{k_1}}, b_{n_{k_2}},\dots$ is a convergent sequence. The limits are not essentially important here. Only the convergence on its own.

Comment: But *why* is it the case that it need not converge yet? :( Why can't I say to look at (bn) and then pick out the convergent sequence (bnk)?

Comment: It is a matter of order: first sequence $(a_n)$ and then sequence $(b_n)$ (or backwards). But not at the same time $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$. Suppose that $0,1,0,1,0,\dots$ is sequence $(a_n)$ ($1$ if $n$ is even and $0$ otherwise) and $1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,\dots$ denotes $b_n$ ($1$ if $n$ is a multiple of $3$ and $0$ otherwise). If I go for $n_k=2k$ then $a_{n_k}$ converges, but $b_{n_k}$ does not.

Comment: Aha. That makes much more sense. It feels a bit weird to wrap my head around it for some reason.