# Cartesian Product of Two Compact Sets is Compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-writing, compactness, product-space

I'm trying to prove that the Cartesian Product of two compact sets is also compact, without the tube-proof thing.

So the rough draft of my proof is:

"Let (x(k), y(k)) be a sequence in AxB, such that x(k) is a sequence in A, and y(k) is a sequence in B. Assume A and B are compact.

As A is compact, there exists a subsequence x1(k) in A, such that x1(k) --> a in A, when k --> infinity. As B is compact, there exists a subsequence y1(k) in B, such that y1(k) --> b in B, when k --> infinity

That means that the subsequence of AxB (x1(k), y1(k)) --> (a,b) in AxB, so AxB is compact."

I thought this was right, but I asked one of my professors and he said it was wrong, but I don't know where I made my mistake. Any help?

Sorry for the bad formatting btw.

Comment: In  a general topological space you cannot use sequential compactness to prove compactness.

Comment: @geetha290krm True, but since the OP included the metric spaces tag,  probably working in metric spaces

Comment: What you are trying to prove here is rather that the product of 2 *[sequentially compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space)* spaces is sequentially compact. What you missed is that if the 2 subsequences $x_1$ and $y_1$ are chosen independently, $(x_1,y_1)$ will *not* be a subsequence of $(x,y)$: $x1(k)=x(\varphi(k))$, $y_1(k)=y(\psi(k))$, $\varphi\ne\psi.$ You should not read the answer. Better rework your proof by yourself. Enjoy!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that if $A$ and $B$ are compact spaces, then $A\times B$ is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984770/proving-that-if-a-and-b-are-compact-spaces-then-a-times-b-is-compact)

Comment: Oh

OH

SHOOT

OK

THANK YOU ANNE

I didn't realize that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are taking your two subsequences independently of each other, so you don't know if the $x$ subsequence matches up with the $y$ subsequence.   You can fix this by doing them one at a time.
First take a converging subsequence of your $x_k$ terms, call it $x_{k_j}$.  This generates a subsequence of your original sequence,
$$(x_{k_j},y_{k_j})$$.
Now you have the subsequence $y_{k_j}$ of a convergent sequence,  so it itself is convergent.  So there is a further subsequence ${y_{k_{j_r}}}$  that is convergent in the $y$ component.  THOSE terms are guaranteed to having matching $x_{k_{j_r}}$ terms,  so
$$(x_{k_{j_r}},y_{k_{j_r}})$$
is a subsequence of the original that is convergent in both components.

This only works if you are dealing with metric spaces,  if you use the open cover definition it is more generalizable

Comment: What has Cauchy to do here?

Comment: I don't understand the Cauchy part much, but thank you so much, I get the rest

Comment: @Arvin I fixed it, I meant convergent, not Cauchy.   If this answered your question, go ahead and mark it with a check next to it.  This shows that the problem has been answered as well as awards a bit of rep.

Comment: @Alan ohhh ok yeah convergent makes far more sense. And got it, I didn't know about the checkmark thing. Thank you so much!